# Hide a div if input is not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a div using

```
if ($("input,textarea").is(":focus")) {
    $("#logos").hide();
} else {
    $("#logos").show();
}
```

I have also tried

```
if ($("#input").is(":focus")) { }
```

and giving the input id of "input", but it seems to not work. It's supposed to work like in mobile google search.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably missing an event handler

```
$("input,textarea").on({
    focus : function() {
        $("#logos").hide();
    },
    blur : function() {
        $("#logos").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not working. this is in the <head> section of the HTML document, inside script tags, and I think that is right. What else could it be? Other jQuery elements work on my document fine.

Comment: And did you wrap it in [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and place those script tags **after** jQuery.

Comment: I didn't wrap it in $(document).ready(), that was the problem. I didn't know you needed it for it to work. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, using the jQuery methods

- show()
- hide()
- focus()
- blur()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.logos').hide();

    $('.focus').focus(function(){
        $('.logos').show();
    });

    $('.focus').blur(function(){
        $('.logos').hide();
    });

});
```

```css
div, textarea {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.logos {
top: 0;
left: 0;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.focus {
top: 0;
left: 112px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="logos">
#logos
</div>

<textarea class="focus">
Focus on me
</textarea>
```